# Spring Security: unable to enable permitAll() to POST API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring security to a POST API -

```
http?.authorizeRequests()
                ?.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/details")?.permitAll()
                ?.antMatchers("/user/**")?.hasRole("admin")
                ?.and()
                ?.formLogin()
```

But, `permitAll()` does not seem to be working. However, if I replace `HttpMethod.POST` with `HttpMethod.GET`, the GET requests under it follow the `antMatcher` rules as expected.

Is there a different way for POST requests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Spring security enables `csrf` by default. So with your config, csrf is enabled.
- `csrf` is not applied to `GET` requests but applied `PUT`, `DELETE`, `POST` and `PATCH`.
- So testing purposes, you can add this to config as well. `http.csrf().disable()` and your `POST` will work

**Note**

Once it started working, you can find out about how to keep `csrf` enabled and send the `csrf` token as part of your modifying requests